# Método não retorna valor correto

Tags: java

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
public class Main {
    public static void Main (String[] args) {
        Metodo R = new Metodo();
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] valores = new int[10];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < valores.length) {
            System.out.println("Insira um número.");
            valores[i] = entrada.nextInt();
            i++;
        } System.out.println(R.somar(valores));
    }
}
public class Metodo {
    public int somar(int[] valores) {
        int soma = 0, i = 0;
        while (i < valores.length) {
            if (valores[i] % 2 == 0.5) {
                soma = soma + valores[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
        return soma;
    }
}
```

Por algum motivo que desconheço, ele retorna sempre 0, mesmo colocando apenas números ímpares, por exemplo, se eu colocar apenas o número 1 em todos os índices do array, ele deveria retornar 10, mas retorna 0.

Como posso resolvê-lo?

Comment: O símbolo % em Java significa resto, logo como vc nunca terá resto de .5, ele não entra. Se vc quiser utilizar divisão, use o símbolo /

Answer (score 4):

Um dos motivos é que no método `somar(int[] valores)` há um loop infinito. Você está usando `i < valores.length` como condição, mas esqueceu de fazer um `i++` após o `if`.

---

Eu não entendi corretamente o objetivo do programa, mas me parece que é para somar os números ímpares de um vetor. Nesse caso, a comparação `valores[i] % 2 == 0.5`, **para números inteiros**, sempre resultará em `false` pois o resto da divisão por 2 (`x % 2`) é igual 1 para ímpares ou 0 para pares.

Então, se você quer somar os ímpares:

```
    while (i < valores.length) {
        if (valores[i] % 2 == 1) {
            soma = soma + valores[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
```

E para os pares:

```
    while (i < valores.length) {
        if (valores[i] % 2 == 0) {
            soma = soma + valores[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Eu esqueci de colocar o i++, corrigido.
Tentei tirar a condição de somar apenas ímpares, mas só retorna o valor do primeiro índice do vetor, se eu colocar 1 e nos outros índices 3, era para retornar 28, porém retorna apenas 1.

Comment: Não entendi. Você retirou a condição e agora só soma o primeiro elemento? Eu fiz o seguinte: http://ideone.com/Rq06Sn. E parece estar funcionando.

Comment: Fiz mais alguns testes e constatei que apenas o último valor do array está sendo exibido, por exemplo, se eu inserir 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, vai aparecer apenas o inteiro 9; por algum motivo, ele não soma, apenas exibe o valor da última posição do array.

Comment: Edita o link do ideone que passei alterando a função `somar` para a forma como está a sua.

Comment: http://ideone.com/lmFvqq

Comment: Aqui somou todos ímpares de `valores`.

Comment: O código que enviei?

Comment: Sim. Digitei (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) e somou 25.

Comment: Estou usando um tratamento com try/catch em outro método que retorna um Integer, será que tem algum problema de retornar um Integer a uma variável int?

Comment: Acho que se você usar `Integer.intValue()` não tem problema.